# Just want my app to fetch an access token to read a public photo gallery with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, access-token

Honestly running out of options, I have tried doing just about every single walkthrough on the Facebook development site and just can't seem to get anything at all to work.

I wrote this gallery application that pulls rss feeds from picasa, and gets the photo infomation to display a dynamic website, it works fine. I ported it to a few other sites like deviant art/flickr/etsy. And no matter what I try I can't manage to get anything from Facebook with all the developer app hoops I have to jump through.

I'll admit, I'm not the strongest coder, php is a bit out of my reach currently as I'm 100% self taught through googling mostly, and I can manage enough javascript and jquery that not much is a problem - but I can't get my Facebook app to do anything.

Is there no simple way to get a generic access_token to view public gallery feeds in the graph api? I don't have any reason for people to log in, I don't need private data, I don't see why there isn't some sort of way to view public albums.

Answer (score 0):

Generic token is generalization for any valid token, more info about token and they usage in Graph API can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#token_terminology).
I think app access token is simplest way for you to read public data, you can retrieve it by sending HTTP GET to following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials
```

more info about App Login can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin).

Comment: i just cant seem to get this to work, even when i call a get with the app id and app secret and despite it returning what looks like an access token, prefermoing a get on the graph of the album id and new access toke, it still shows the error "A user access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: @Gazow are you sure that this album is public? can you provide it id?

Comment: yeh its public, i checked several times and everything--320448691325505

Comment: @Gazow sorry, but this album is not public, public album means that you can view it even without logging to facebook and consuming it content through Graph API. Check this album id 10150664699326729 its public album from Facebook page.

Comment: so no matter what the album says, because it belongs to a person and not a page it can never be public in that it can be accessed through the graph without having the user login? gosh that sounds awfuly stupid

Comment: @Gazow public in facebook means public to all **facebook** users, so you need to get `user_photos` permission from user before downloading his photos to you site, you can read more about album privacy [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/privacy/photos/privacy-for-photo-albums)